# Mathrm within align block doesn't work?

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\begin{align} 
& nH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{n} 
& mH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{m-1} + H_{2}O
\end{align}
```

The above works but I want to get rid of the italicized equation. So I did the following

```
\begin{align} 
\mathrm{
& nH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{n} 
& mH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{m-1} + H_{2}O 
}
\end{align}
```

It gives me the "Missing } inserted" error :(

Comment: You should have a look at the `chemformula` package.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about the existence of such package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `\mathrm`:

```
\begin{align} 
& \mathrm{nH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{n} 
}
&\mathrm{ mH_{2}O + ^* \rightarrow H_{2}O^*_{m-1} + H_{2}O 
}
\end{align}
```

Everything should be closed before  `&` (or `\\` etc.)  next to the opening `{`.